# Anonymous HTTP Web Request

Tags: vb.net, system.net.httpwebrequest

I created http request application to test my web site qulatiy (see below).

```
 Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(webAddress)
 Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()

 Request.Method = "Get"

 Dim Reader As New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream)
 Dim Html As String = Reader.ReadToEnd()
```

In this case, I would like to create anonymous request without catching the response. How can I do that?

Comment: what do u mean by anonymous request?

Comment: I mean that I create a request and send it. But I didn't catch the response. So, the server gets this anonymous request. But the server didn't know where to response.

Comment: any reason u dont want to read the response?

Comment: Yes. Beside I don't want to catch response. Because I would like to that the server didn't know where to response.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14333532/922198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so, u have to get a little low level , working with sockets

[TcpCient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) in this case

Sample code

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets


Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim tcpcli = New TcpClient()
        tcpcli.Connect("google.co.in", 80)

        Dim stream As NetworkStream = tcpcli.GetStream()
        Dim reqdata As String = String.Format("GET / HTTP/1.1{0}Host: www.google.co.in{0}Connection: Close{0}{0}", vbCrLf)
        Dim reqbytes() As Byte = Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reqdata)

        stream.Write(reqbytes, 0, reqbytes.Length)

        stream.Close()
        stream.Dispose()

        tcpcli.Close()



    End Sub

End Module
```

Network capture via wireshark (no response received)
[image: no response receive as no response was read from socket]

Answer (score 0):

You can make a web request anonymously by using [ProxySharp](https://github.com/m-henderson/ProxySharp). It basically makes the web request behind a random vpn each time. This makes it look like the request is coming from a different IP address on each request.